# How to run a function created in the shell script in an AIX server?

Tags: linux, function, shell, aix

I had created a shell script in a linux machine, it is executing fine in that machine as well as in other linux machine but when I am running the same script in an AIX machine it is not working.

For ex-
**script1**

```
print "Hello"
a()
{
 print "Welcome"
}

b()
{
 print "Bye"
}

a
b
```

While executing this script in a linux machine the output is

```
Hello
Welcome
Bye
```

But while executing it in an AIX machine the output is

```
Hello
```

I think it is not calling the function `a` and `b` in the AIX machine.
So can anybody give me solution to run the script in both Linux and Aix machine.

Comment: What if you define it like `function a () { ... }`? http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-getstartedbash/

Comment: It is not working for AIX machine I tried it

Answer (score 0):

-try to define function without paranthesis, e.g.:

function a {
 print "Welcome"
}

-don't forget to define shell - #!/bin/sh

-perhaps try to use another shell implementations (ksh, bash, ...)

-just in case, I saw somewhere that on AIX you can't write both, opening and closing curly braces on the same line { }